# Why are Ant lib folders different

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, ant

I am using Eclipse Helios with Tomcat 7 on Windows and have imported Apache Ant-1.8.4 and works fine but I had to set up the same environment on another machine and when I attempted to build the project using Ant in Eclipse it failed with the following message;

```
C:\eclipsehelios\workspace\projectname\build.xml:207: Problem: failed to 
create task or type emmajava

Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken  
place
```

I have had this error before and just required to ensure the build file had the correct path to the Ant folder but this didn't resolve things this time.  I found by copying in the following files to the Ant's lib folder solved the problem but these were not required in my own PC and wondered if someone would tell me if this was the correct way to resolve this problem and if so why do I not require these on my own PC?

```
antlr-2.7.6.jar

commons-beanutils-1.8.3-javadoc.jar
commons-beanutils-1.8.3-sources.jar
commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
commons-beanutils-bean-collections-1.8.3.jar
commons-beanutils-core-1.8.3.jar

commons-cli-1.2-javadoc.jar
commons-cli-1.2-sources.jar
commons-cli-1.2.jar
commons-logging.jar

ganymed.jar
guava-13.0.1-sources.jar.sav
guava-13.0.1.jar.sav
guava-gwt-13.0.1-sources.jar.sav
guava-r07-javadoc.jar.sav
guava-r07-sources.jar.sav
guava-r07.jar.sav
jna.jar

svnant-1.3.1.jar    
svnant.jar
svnClientAdapter.jar
svnjavahl.jar
svnkit.jar
```

EDIT:
If I click on the line "C:\eclipsehelios\workspace\projectname\build.xml:207" it goes to the following section of the build file with the top line "

```
<emmajava enabled="${emma.enabled}" libclasspathref="emma.lib"  
fullmetadata="yes" filter="${emma.filter}" sourcepath="src" 
classname="the.company.domain.test.EmmaLoginMain">

    <classpath>
      <pathelement path="test" />
      <pathelement path="build/classes" />
      <pathelement path="build_tests/classes" />
      <pathelement path="test" />
         <fileset dir="${libDir}">
         <include name="**/*.jar" />
         </fileset>
             <fileset dir="${tomcat_lib}">
             <include name="**/*.jar" />
             </fileset>
             <fileset dir="${test_lib}">
                <include name="**/*.jar" />
             </fileset>
      </classpath>

      <!-- regular <java> options are still available: -->
      <!--<arg value="somearg" /> -->

      <!-- <emmajava> option extensions [see the reference manual for
         complete details]: -->
      <xml outfile="${test.reports.dir}/emma/coverage.xml" />
      <txt outfile="${test.reports.dir}/emma/coverage.txt" />
      <html outfile="${test.reports.dir}/emma/coverage.html" />
</emmajava>
```

Comment: can you show what is at 207 line in build.xml??

Comment: @Prashant I have added in the section of the build file.  Although I have just discovered in my PC there is a jar that is not on the new machine.  In the lib folder of Ant on my machine I have a file named ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar

Comment: You appear to be missing the Emma ANT task jars. See the following doco: http://emma.sourceforge.net/userguide_single/userguide.html.  Please note you should also consider using Jacoco instead. Emma appears to be abandonware.